# How to read specific line and then add it to dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have file like this and I want to read it from line `by walk` until line `car` and then add it to the dictionary where key will be a time `7.00 - 8.00` and value will be number `150`.

For example

```
by_walk = {"7.00 - 8.00":150, "8.00 - 9.00":175 and et cetera}
car = {"7.00 - 8.00":150, "8.00 - 9.00":175 and et cetera}
bus = {"7.00 - 8.00":150, "8.00 - 9.00":175 and et cetera}
```

How can I do this?

```
By walk
7.00 - 8.00 - 150
8.00 - 9.00 - 175
9.00 - 10.00 - 120
10.00 - 11.00 - 30
11.00 - 12.00 - 10
12.00 - 13.00 - 10
13.00 - 14.00 - 10
14.00 - 15.00 - 10
15.00 - 16.00 - 10
16.00 - 17.00 - 175
17.00 - 18.00 - 150
18.00 - 19.00 - 50
Car
7.00 - 8.00 - 150
8.00 - 9.00 - 175
9.00 - 10.00 - 120
10.00 - 11.00 - 30
11.00 - 12.00 - 10
12.00 - 13.00 - 10
13.00 - 14.00 - 10
14.00 - 15.00 - 10
15.00 - 16.00 - 10
16.00 - 17.00 - 175
17.00 - 18.00 - 150
18.00 - 19.00 - 50
Bus
7.00 - 8.00 - 150
8.00 - 9.00 - 175
9.00 - 10.00 - 120
10.00 - 11.00 - 30
11.00 - 12.00 - 10
12.00 - 13.00 - 10
13.00 - 14.00 - 10
14.00 - 15.00 - 10
15.00 - 16.00 - 10
16.00 - 17.00 - 175
17.00 - 18.00 - 150
18.00 - 19.00 - 50
```

Thanks for all the answers, I have an issue I do not know how to read line from car to bus, here is my code:

```
 by_walk = {}
 car = {}
 bus = {}
 for line in open("test.txt"):
     if line.strip() != "Car":
         if line.strip() == "By walk":
             continue
         line = line.rsplit('-', 1)
         by_walk[line[0].strip()] = int(line[1])
     elif line.strip() == "Car":
          break
for line in open("test.txt"):
```

But after first loop I do not know what to do and what code I need to write.

Comment: have you made an attempt?

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what the problem is, what you expected, what you got, and any traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

The variable `q` is only here in case there are "time/count" rows before the first mode of transport (that would probably be a bug in the file). A row that starts with a letter is assumed to be a mode of transort, any other row is a time/count. That could be adapted (remove comment lines, for instance).

```
by_walk = {}
car = {}
bus = {}

tbl = {"By walk": by_walk, "Car": car, "Bus": bus}

q = False
with open("test.txt", "rt") as f:
    for s in f:
        s = s.rstrip("\r\n")
        if s[0].isalpha():
            q = True
            h = tbl[s]
        elif q:
            u, v = s.rsplit("-", 1)
            u = u.strip()
            v = int(v)
            h[u] = v
```

It's also possible to accomodate unknown modes of transport by using an empty `tbl` and only adding modes of transport when they are encountered.

```
from collections import defaultdict
tbl = defaultdict(dict)

q = False
with open("test.txt", "rt") as f:
    for s in f:
        s = s.rstrip("\r\n")
        if s[0].isalpha():
            q = True
            h = tbl[s]
        elif q:
            u, v = s.rsplit("-", 1)
            u = u.strip()
            v = int(v)
            h[u] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the file line by line and see if the line contains`-`. If it does then you know that from there you have to start making the dictionary. Otherwise you append the formed dictionary to the list.
This code does that -

```
travel_list = []
time_dict = dict()
with open('tmp.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        s = line.rsplit('-', 1)
        if '-' in line:
            time_dict[s[0]] = s[1].rstrip()
        else:
            time_dict = dict()
            travel_list.append({line.rstrip(): time_dict})
```

Output:

```
Out[20]: 
[{'By walk': {'7.00 - 8.00 ': ' 150',
   '8.00 - 9.00 ': ' 175',
   '9.00 - 10.00 ': ' 120',
   '10.00 - 11.00 ': ' 30',
   '11.00 - 12.00 ': ' 10',
   '12.00 - 13.00 ': ' 10',
   '13.00 - 14.00 ': ' 10',
   '14.00 - 15.00 ': ' 10',
   '15.00 - 16.00 ': ' 10',
   '16.00 - 17.00 ': ' 175',
   '17.00 - 18.00 ': ' 150',
   '18.00 - 19.00 ': ' 50'}},
 {'Car': {'7.00 - 8.00 ': ' 150',
   '8.00 - 9.00 ': ' 175',
   '9.00 - 10.00 ': ' 120',
   '10.00 - 11.00 ': ' 30',
   '11.00 - 12.00 ': ' 10',
   '12.00 - 13.00 ': ' 10',
   '13.00 - 14.00 ': ' 10',
   '14.00 - 15.00 ': ' 10',
   '15.00 - 16.00 ': ' 10',
   '16.00 - 17.00 ': ' 175',
   '17.00 - 18.00 ': ' 150',
   '18.00 - 19.00 ': ' 50'}},
 {'Bus': {'7.00 - 8.00 ': ' 150',
   '8.00 - 9.00 ': ' 175',
   '9.00 - 10.00 ': ' 120',
   '10.00 - 11.00 ': ' 30',
   '11.00 - 12.00 ': ' 10',
   '12.00 - 13.00 ': ' 10',
   '13.00 - 14.00 ': ' 10',
   '14.00 - 15.00 ': ' 10',
   '15.00 - 16.00 ': ' 10',
   '16.00 - 17.00 ': ' 175',
   '17.00 - 18.00 ': ' 150',
   '18.00 - 19.00 ': ' 50'}}]
```

Comment: Note that `len(line.split('-')) > 1` is equivalent to `"-" in line` (you could also store the result in `s` *before* the `if` rather than split twice) and `split/join` can be replaced with a single `rsplit`. Also, you are going to store a number as string, with an extra linefeed at the end (may or may not be a problem depending on context). Last but not least, you are putting everything in a single dict: the mode of transport is lost.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Edited the answer to make it better

Comment: `"a-b-c".rsplit("-", 1)` → `["a-b", "c"]`

Comment: So sorry, this is what happens when you are in a hurry. I think its okay now.

Answer (score 0):

IN:

```
import re

dict1 = dict()
readValues = iter(re.split('\n', open("file.txt", "r").read()))
next(readValues)
for v in readValues:
    rV = re.split("(([0-9- ]{1,2}.[0-9- ]{1,2}) - ([0-9- ]{1,2}.[0-9- ]{1,2})\w+)", v)
    dict1[rV[1]] = rV[4].replace("-", "").strip()

print(dict1)
```

OUT:

```
 {'7.00 - 8.00': '150', '8.00 - 9.00': '175', '9.00 - 10.00': '120', '10.00 - 11.00': '30', '11.00 - 12.00': '10', '12.00 - 13.00': '10', '13.00 - 14.00': '10', '14.00 - 15.00': '10', '15.00 - 16.00': '10', '16.00 - 17.00': '175', '17.00 - 18.00': '150', '18.00 - 19.00': '50'}
```